# Image Slider with next image preview

Tags: jquery, slider

[image]

Is there any similar slider available with jquery , where the second image preview is visible at the corner of the slider ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created my best attempt at this question, I hope its sufficient but I'm not happy with it myself as it uses background images. If you need help understanding it then please ask. You can change the images by changing the list urls. I think I made it dynamic enough to expand with more images. The sizes should be changeable with css fairly easily.

To make it work better you could probably have it so when you hovered over the preview it was displayed as the "main" display until you exited hover state.

**Note that this unfortunatly only works on some browsers (tested on Firefox, doesn't work on chrome). This might be fixable, basicly you'd need to find out how to skewX on chrome.**

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/dyico?editors=001)

**JQuery**

```
var elements = $("#urlList").children();
var urlArray = [];
$(elements).each(function(index){   
    urlArray.push($(this).html());  
});

var index = 0;
var currentImage = urlArray[0];
var previewImage = urlArray[1];

$('#next').click(function(){
  index += 1;
  if(index > urlArray.length-1){
    index = 0;
  }
  $('.box').css("background-image","url('"+urlArray[index]+"')");
  var previewIndex = index+1;
  if(previewIndex > urlArray.length-1){
    previewIndex = 0;
  }
  $(".insideBox").css("background-image","url('"+urlArray[previewIndex]+"')")
});
$('#Previous').click(function(){
  index -= 1;
  if(index < 0){
    index = urlArray.length -1;
  }
  $('.box').css("background-image","url('"+urlArray[index]+"')");
  var previewIndex = index +1;
  if(previewIndex > urlArray.length-1){
    previewIndex = 0;
  }
  $(".insideBox").css("background-image","url('"+urlArray[previewIndex]+"')")
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <ul id="urlList">
    <li>http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg</li>
    <li>http://hdlatestwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Green-Bubbles-Awesome-Background.jpg</li>
    <li>http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg</li>
  </ul>
    <div class="insideBox">
    </div>
  <a id="next"> > </a>
  <a id="Previous"> < </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg');
  background-size:100%;
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:1;
}

#urlList{
 display:none; 
}
.insideBox{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url("http://hdlatestwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Green-Bubbles-Awesome-Background.jpg");
  background-size:100%;
  border:solid white;
  opacity:0.8;
  right:-5em;
  transform:skewX(-55deg);
  overflow:hidden;
}

.insideBox:hover{
  opacity:1;
}

a{
    margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
    width:20px;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  border:solid 1px white;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  border-radius:20px;
}
a#next{
  right:0;

}
```